# Function works locally but not on AWS Lambda

Tags: aws-lambda, jsreport

I'm using `jsreport` to render HTML and generate a PDF file and it works locally, but on Lambda, it throws this error:

```
{
  "errorMessage": "Error during rendering report: Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined",
  "errorType": "TypeError",
  "stackTrace": [
    "Phantom.execute (/var/task/node_modules/jsreport-phantom-pdf/lib/phantom.js:169:53)",
    "/var/task/node_modules/jsreport-core/lib/render/render.js:118:23",
    "tryCatcher (/var/task/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/util.js:16:23)",
    "Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (/var/task/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:512:31)",
    "Promise._settlePromise (/var/task/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:569:18)",
    "Promise._settlePromise0 (/var/task/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:614:10)",
    "Promise._settlePromises (/var/task/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:693:18)",
    "Async._drainQueue (/var/task/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:133:16)",
    "Async._drainQueues (/var/task/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:143:10)",
    "Immediate.Async.drainQueues (/var/task/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:17:14)",
    "runCallback (timers.js:672:20)",
    "tryOnImmediate (timers.js:645:5)",
    "processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:617:5)"
  ]
}
```

Same environment variables, same Node version.

Comment: For tips on asking a good question, please see: [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Just quick FYI on this, if you're running a version of node LOCALLY that is HIGHER than current AWS runtime you can get different versions of node modules with different features enabled on AWS, if you're testing locally make sure you're using the same node version as you are on aws.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turned out, it was a problem of this library: [node-app-root-path](https://github.com/inxilpro/node-app-root-path).

I fixed it by passing the correct `rootDirectory` option to jsreport.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the line that generates the error above: https://github.com/jsreport/jsreport-phantom-pdf/blob/ad8d42e640348abffe77f2fed818528bee3eed98/lib/phantom.js#L169

```
var phantom = this.definition.options.phantoms.filter(function (p) {
  return p.version === request.template.phantom.phantomjsVersion
})
```

which implies the object path `options.phantoms` is undefined.

You'll have to check how `definitions` is set up in your Lambda.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I figured it out.